# ASP.NET Core Many-to-many relationship problems, trouble with include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to display the Positions of Employees in Department views. At the moment I am currently displaying only Employees. How can I include employee positions? The model relationship Employees and Positions is many-to-many, the relationship  Department and Employees is also many-to-many.
There were no problems when the relationship of Positions and Employees was one to many.
I was trying to add to the *DivisionEmployeeViewModel* property a collection `public IEnumerable<EmployeePosition> EmployeePositionList { get; set;` }
But I don’t know how to implement it further. I'm stumped.

Method-actions in DivisionController

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
        {
            var model = new DivisionEmployeeViewModel
            {
                DivisionEmployeeList = await _db.DivisionEmployeesModel.Include(x => x.Employee)
                .Include(x => x.Division).Where(x => x.Division_Id == id).ToListAsync(),

                DivisionEmployees = new DivisionEmployee()
                {
                    Division_Id = id
                },

                Division = await _db.Divisions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)
            };

            List<int> tempAssignedList = model.DivisionEmployeeList.Select(x => x.Employee_Id).ToList();

            var tempList = await _db.Employees.Where(x => !tempAssignedList.Contains(x.Id)).ToListAsync();

            model.DivisionEmployeeListDropDown = tempList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.FullName,
                Value = x.Id.ToString()
            });

            return View(model);
        }
```

My repo https://github.com/ValencyJacob/DepartmentManagementApp-Many-to-Many/tree/master/DepartmentManagement

Comment: You can get EF to write the code for you. Add the relevant tables to the DB (Employee, Department, Position, EmployeeDepartment, EmployeePosition), add the relationships (table names with a single word are the 1 end, table names with 2 words are the M end), then tell EF to scaffold the db again (to a new folder) and use a diff tool to import the changes

Comment: ps; in EFcore, M:M relationships are done by breaking into two 1:Ms, and you then just have Employee.EmployeePositions collection of EmployeePosition entity, which has a Position property, so it's like `myEmployee.Select(e => e.EmployeePositions.Position.Name)` to get the names of all the positions the E holds, after loading them by e.g. `context.Employees.Include(e => e.EmployeePositions).ThenInclude(ep => ep.Position)`

Comment: Caius Jard 
I did. But I need to get the positions of the Employees, not all the positions. EmployeePositionList = await _db.EmployeePositions.Include(x => x.Position).Include(x => x.Employee)
                .Where(x => x.Position_Id == 0_0No ideas).ToListAsync(), // Tried so to

Comment: Sorry, typo there.. `myEmployee.EmployeePositions.Select(ep => ep.Position.Name)`, but I don't really understand what youre trying to put in your Where.. `_db.EmployeePositions` is indeed fulfillling requirement "i need to get the positions of the employees". For a single employee it's `var posFor123 = _db.EmployeePositions.Include(ep=> ep.Position).Where(ep => ep.EmployeeId = 123)` , then you get an enumerable of EmployeePosition and you can pull the positions out, perhaps like `posFor123.Select(ep => ep.Position.Name)`

Comment: Caius Jard yes, it's my bad =( Thx a lot Master! I didn't see my mistake. I change this code to this 'EmployeePositionList = await _db.EmployeePositions.Include(x => x.Position).Include(x => x.Employee).ToListAsync(),' and modified my View. I don't know why I tried to use Where =(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, typo there.. myEmployee.EmployeePositions.Select(ep => ep.Position.Name), but I don't really understand what youre trying to put in your Where.. _db.EmployeePositions is indeed fulfillling requirement "i need to get the positions of the employees". For a single employee it's var posFor123 = _db.EmployeePositions.Include(ep=> ep.Position).Where(ep => ep.EmployeeId = 123) , then you get an enumerable of EmployeePosition and you can pull the positions out, perhaps like posFor123.Select(ep => ep.Position.Name) – **Caius Jard**